# How can I get the file name of the function that is passed to my decorator in python?

Tags: python, metaclass, python-datamodel

I want to get the original file/scriptname, etc of the function that is being decorated. How can I do that?

```
   def decorate(fn):
        def wrapped():
            return "scriptname: " + fn.scriptname?  
        return wrapped
```

I tried using `fn.__code__` but that gave me more stuff that I needed. I could parse that string to get the function name, but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it

Comment: on a side note relying on this kind of stuff in production code is usually a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return "filename: " + fn.func_code.co_filename
```

Comment: It's important to note that this is relying on _implementation details_ and may not work outside of CPython. Using `inspect` is the actual correct answer, but why go for correct when the one-liner is easier, right? :|

Comment: @Matthew Trevor Correct, The `inspect` is better, I didn't know about this and learned it from gnibbler's answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(fn)
```

This won't work for [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) though, you have to fall back to `inspect.getmodule` for those.